# Sort a Query by a field in a related (belongs to) table?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Rails 2.3.5 / Ruby 1.8.6

I have a 'teams' table that contains a 'center' id (center_id) field (teams belongs to center and center has many teams).   In the views, I'm using the name of the center:

```
Controller (sorting by team 'name':
 @teams= Team.find(:all, :order => "name ASC")
View:
 <%=h team.center.center_name %>
```

How can I sort the query by the by center name?  Like:

```
@teams= Team.find(:all, :order => "center.center_name ASC name ASC")
```

I'm not even sure if this is possible...   Should I be trying to solve this be adding logic to the "@teams.each do |team|" loop?    Or maybe by collecting the query results into a normal array and then sorting the array?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're pretty close.  Do you have a 'centers' table?  If so try:

```
@teams= Team.find(:all, :include=>:center, :order => "centers.center_name ASC, teams.name ASC")
```